# Scintilla custom syntax highlighting not working

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I have a Scintilla control that I create in C#, and the syntax highlighting doesn't work. It sets the font correctly which tells me that the file is being loaded, but the syntax highlighting doesn't work at all:

```
Scintilla r = new Scintilla();
r.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
r.ConfigurationManager.IsUserEnabled = true;
r.ConfigurationManager.CustomLocation = "langs.xml";
r.ConfigurationManager.Language = "rb";
r.Margins[0].Width = 40;
r.Indentation.UseTabs = true;
r.Indentation.IndentWidth = 4;
r.Indentation.ShowGuides = true;
r.Indentation.TabIndents = true;
r.Indentation.TabWidth = 4;
r.Indentation.SmartIndentType = SmartIndent.Simple;
```

and the configuration file is this:

http://codepad.org/DAjCrlPT

in langs.xml. (The code won't fit here.) Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, my config file was wrong for some reason.